# Visual studio extensibility allows us to put extra items in any menu?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vsx

I mean, I have an add-in that will be applied to a given project. I'd like to know if it's possible to add a menu item for my add-in to the context menu that appears when you right click any project in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's possible. Is that all you wanted to know?

The [Visual Studio Extensibility Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx) is your starting point for all VSX work. Start by downloading and installing the Visual Studio SDK, looking at the examples and documentation it contains.

Then, feel free to return to StackOverflow to start a more specific question.

Comment: Well, I'd like to know how to add it to that context menu, then. I've seen it is easy to define if I want to add my add-in to the Tools, Test, menu etc. But I can do this because I know their names. How should I proceed so I can add it to the project's right click context menu?

Comment: First, please edit your question when you add more information like the above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are aware of the vsct syntax then [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826118%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) document should help you in adding the commands.

For adding into context menu take a look into [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsmenus.idm_vs_ctxt_projnode.aspx)