# Visual Studio extensibility

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in

Based on our project we created several item and project templates which after installation using our installer works perfectly. this was really good step as it avoids spending time on setting up new projects or modules inside our enterprise application. Now we want to move forward and create something similar to the context menu inside visual studio when u click Views or Controls folder inside ASP.NET MVC application and in other types of projects as well (for example when u click your right mouse button on your WPF application, under Add menu u get different items which avoids opening new window where u have to search for item time.

My goal is to create add in or whatever it is called to make it even easier to work with our SDK so for example when developer right-clicks on project we want to have our own menu items under New menu so developers will be able to add OURPROGRAM View, OURPROGRAM view with validation. can anyone assist me with this? or how provide good examples of this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual studio extensibility allows us to put extra items in any menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220735/visual-studio-extensibility-allows-us-to-put-extra-items-in-any-menu)

Answer (score 0):

Look for the Visual Studio SDK documentation on MSDN.

There is an open source Iron Python project which is your best resource. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165436(v=vs.80).aspx

Also on MSDN there is a walkthru for creating a basic project system.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512973.aspx

Comment: That's not an answer and We all know what MSDN is and use it on daily basics but I asked for good tutorial for starting point

Comment: @Rati_Ge Actually, it's a perfectly good answer. You've been pointed in the direction of everything you need to get started on your project.

Comment: it was without any links before I posted my comment and secondly do u really think documentation page and sample for Visual Studio 2005 is really good direction? and nothing changed after that version? I am not asking for pointing to links which explains how to create project templates what I want is to have my own item under new Add context menu item when u click your right mouse button on Visual Studio project inside solution explorer.